# Jenkins integration with MVN TestNG project error

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, automation, testng

This is the error log, its my Jenkins console  output :

```
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] Results:
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mFailures: [m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m  mas1.test:18 » WebDriver invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
Build ...[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mTests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] 
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1;31mBUILD FAILURE[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;34mINFO[m] Total time: 19.664 s
[[1;34mINFO[m] Finished at: 2018-12-11T13:47:23+05:30
[[1;34mINFO[m] [1m------------------------------------------------------------------------[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal [32morg.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M2:test[m [1m(default-test)[m on project [36mapps[m: [1;31mThere are test failures.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31m[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mPlease refer to /home/ghost/IdeaProjects/apps/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1;31mPlease refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.[m
[[1;31mERROR[m] -> [1m[Help 1][m
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[[1;31mERROR[m] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[[1;31mERROR[m] 
[[1;31mERROR[m] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[[1;31mERROR[m] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE
```

in /home/ghost/IdeaProjects/apps  here

> i try this code `mvn clean test`  its build success and open browser
>   and close

but when i run through Jenkins only its a problem

in Jenkins build i select execute shell and enter this command

```
cd /home/ghost/IdeaProjects/apps
mvn clean test
```

how to fix this error

**Jenkins Jenkins ver. 2.150.1 

java -version: openjdk version "1.8.0_191"**

Comment: in Jenkins execute this shell command mvn -version, whether Jenkins is getting mvn first

Comment: same issue and  my mvn version `Apache Maven 3.5.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.0-12-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix`

Comment: is this output you are getting from Jenkins console "i mean the mvn version output" .

Comment: and by console it clearly tells " WebDriver invalid argument: can't kill an exited process", what exactly you are doing in that testcase

Comment: didnt do anything just run open browser and get url then close that all

Comment: You need to check .dump file and resolve issue, from this location /home/ghost/IdeaProjects/apps/target/surefire-reports

Comment: @IshitaShah this location empty 1mvn clean test` only give error through jenkins :(

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Jenkins integration and your local works fine. most probably your problem is headless issue. Another thing is browser is not opened correctly.

I went through such a situation and my solution is use headless browser and configure it correctly according to both platforms. If your jenkins server Runs in different platform eg:- Local is Windows Jenkins is in Linux. then you have to test it in both platforms. just check its run correctly in your jenkins by capture images before and while during running.

here is the script which is match for linux as well as windows

```
}else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("HLChrome")){
            //Headless chrome browser and configure
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
            chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-gpu");
//            chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1400,2100"); // linux should be activate
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

If you are using linux environment, you have to add --no-sandbox as well and also specific window size settings. --no-sandbox is no needed in windows if you set user container properly.

disable-gpu Only on Windows. Other platforms no longer require it. The --disable-gpu flag is a temporary work around for a few bugs.